# Validating the data inside postgres table

Tags: postgresql, docker

I have launched a postgres container. By injecting script.sql at docker entrypoint, I created database, schema, tables and have inserted data into them. Docker Logs says that all table creation and data insertion is successful .

But How can I validate the data insertion? Below commands didn't help

```
       List of relations
   Schema   |         Name         | Type  |  Owner
------------+----------------------+-------+----------
 my_db      | users                | table | postgres
 my_db      | audit_log            | table | postgres
 my_db      | config               | table | postgres

(3 rows)

my_db=# SELECT * FROM my_db.users
my_db-# SELECT * FROM users
my_db-# SELECT * FROM my_db.users;
```

What is wrong here? Please help.

Comment: End each `select` statement with a semicolon `;`

Answer (score 0):

You should use

```
\c my_db
```

to connect to your database. And then:

```
SELECT * FROM users;
```

To query your table into your database.

It seems that you understood this part, but everything should be done using postgresql command line, so inside the docker container.

Comment: Hi @thibaultbl, I am already connected to database with /c and also set search_path to "my_db";

Comment: Even after that, the query is not returning anything

Comment: Try to enter several time ";" followed by enter before your query, sometimes, postgresql is stuck in old query if you forgot ";" previously.